# Can an iframe render offline with a service worker?

Tags: javascript, iframe, service-worker

I have my domain, `abc.com`, and an iframe inside my page `123.com`. I own the code for each domain.

With a service worker I can load `abc.com` while offline but my iframe for `123.com` does not load, even if I add its files to my `cache.addAll` call.

How can I get my iframe to render while offline? Examples welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    will render offline

    <!-- will not render offline -->
    <iframe src="123.com"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your iframe has to have a service worker of its own too. Can you test embedding [this link](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/) as an iframe in your code? Don't forget to open it before testing offline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loading an `<iframe>` is [very similar](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-destination) to loading a full page in a new tab/window. The request for the `<iframe>.src` will trigger any `fetch` handlers on a service worker whose scope covers the `<iframe>.src`, i.e. in your case, a service worker whose scope covers `https://123.com/`.

The `FetchEvent` that's passed to the `fetch` handler will have a `request.mode` of `'navigate'`, just like a navigation to a new page in a standalone tab/window would have.